# How can i search text in a file using react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, search, full-text-search, file-search

I want to implement search in a react project where i have a file locally in the project folder and i want to search from that file.

Should i load the file data into a state variable? not sure but i don't think that is something i should implement since the file can be very large in size.

Any help or direction would be appreciated, thanks!

Currently i'm storing the data into a state and then performing the search. I wanted to know if there are any better ways to do the same.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are right about it. loading a file in state first of all can be a bad idea because its loaded like an Array Buffer or sort, so its all binary not exact text. Hence search would be a problem.

This usecase is more for the backend side to handle in Real World scenarios.